# Can I insert a android:defaultValue trait for RingtonePreference, via XML?

Tags: android, xml, default, preferences, ringtone

Is there a way to add a default value in a RingtonePreference, via XML?  For example, here's what my preference.xml looks like.

```
<RingtonePreference android:key="alarm"
android:title="Alarm" android:name="Alarm"
android:summary="Select an alarm"
android:ringtoneType="alarm" android:showDefault="true" />
```

If possible, I'd like to set the RingtonePreference to the default ringtone, like this:

```
<RingtonePreference android:key="alarm"
android:title="Alarm" android:name="Alarm"
android:summary="Select an alarm"
android:ringtoneType="alarm" android:showDefault="true"
android:defaultValue="defaultRingtone" />
```

Comment: Tried the following 2 with no luck:android:
defaultValue="Default ringtone"
android:defaultValue="0"

Comment: Having more luck with this: defaultValue="".  This sets the default to "silent," however.  It seems RingtonePreference expects a string value, where a ringtone is located.  To get the default value, then, I'd have to get the string for the default ringtone in Settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out a work-around, in setting the default ringtone.

For the people who uses both a `RingtonePreference` and `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues()`, `android:defaultValue` on a `RingtonePreference` takes in a string to a ringtone's URI.  By providing an empty string, you're defaulting the preference to "silence," while other strings will probably lead to no valid URI.

The work-around, then, is to provide a bogus string, such as `android:defaultValue="defaultRingtone"`:

```
<RingtonePreference android:key="alarm"
android:title="Alarm" android:name="Alarm"
android:summary="Select an alarm"
android:ringtoneType="alarm" android:showDefault="true"
android:defaultValue="defaultRingtone" />
```

When calling `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues()`, grab the preference, and check if the bogus string is being stored:

```
// Set the stored preferences to default values defined in options.xml
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.layout.options, false);

// Check the stored string value, under the RingtonPreference tag
final SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final String savedUri = savedState.getString("alarm", "");

// By default, set the alarm's URI to null
Uri alarmUri = null;

// Check if a String was actually provided
if(savedUri.length() > 0) {

  // If the stored string is the bogus string...
  if(savedUri.equals("defaultRingtone")) {

    // Set the alarm to this system's default alarm.
    alarmUri = Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI;

    // Save this alarm's string, so that we don't have to go through this again
    final SharedPreferences.Editor saveEditor = saveState.edit();
    saveEditor.putString("alarm", alarmUri.toString());
    saveEditor.commit();
  }

  // Otherwise, retrieve the URI as normal.
  else {
    alarmUri = Uri.parse(savedUri);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can define the default in the XML.
As you said, it needs a URI.
Simply put the default URI for what you need.
For example, for a default alarm sound you would put:

```
<RingtonePreference android:key="alarm"
android:title="Alarm" android:name="Alarm"
android:summary="Select an alarm"
android:ringtoneType="alarm" android:showDefault="true"
android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/alarm_alert" />
```

For a notification you would put:

```
android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
```

Etc.