# RingtonePreference Default value

Tags: android

I have this code for my Preference screen,

```
<RingtonePreference 
    android:key="notification_sound" 
    android:ringtoneType="notification" 
    android:title="Notification Sound" 
    android:showDefault="true" 
    android:showSilent="true" />
```

i want set default value for RingtonePreference to `Default Notification Sound` in xml, how can do it ?

Thanks

Comment: I found this on SO:

[RingtonePreference DefaultValue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235018/can-i-insert-a-androiddefaultvalue-trait-for-ringtonepreference-via-xml

Answer (score 31, accepted):

i found solution, thanks to `Joe`, defaultValue Must be :

```
android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
```

Comment: @d-a-v-o-o-d after performing **'Inspect Code...'** through Android Sudio Analyze menu, I am getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'content://settings/system/notification_sound'`