# How to set default ringtone from ringtones programmatically

Tags: android, ringtonemanager

I am trying to set an mp3 from the raw folder as the phone's ringtone. The ringtone is stored in the ringtones folder and is an option to select, however I would like to have the ringtone selected as default. How can I do this programmatically?

```
private void setRingtone() {
        AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFileDescriptor;
        ((AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).setRingerMode(2);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/appkeeda", this.fNmae);
        if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Uri parse = Uri.parse(this.fPAth);
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        try {
            openAssetFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(parse, "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            openAssetFileDescriptor = null;
        }
        try {
            byte[] bArr = new byte[1024];
            FileInputStream createInputStream = openAssetFileDescriptor.createInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            for (int read = createInputStream.read(bArr); read != -1; read = createInputStream.read(bArr)) {
                fileOutputStream.write(bArr, 0, read);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("_data", file.getAbsolutePath());
        contentValues.put("title", mp3s[position]);
        contentValues.put("mime_type", "audio/mp3");
        contentValues.put("_size", Long.valueOf(file.length()));
        contentValues.put("artist", Integer.valueOf(R.string.app_name));
        contentValues.put("is_ringtone", Boolean.valueOf(true));
        contentValues.put("is_notification", Boolean.valueOf(false));
        contentValues.put("is_alarm", Boolean.valueOf(false));
        contentValues.put("is_music", Boolean.valueOf(false));
        try {
            //Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Ringtone set successfully"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 1, contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath()), contentValues));
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Ringtone feature is not working"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Ringtone selection part of it in a PreferenceScreen, you can create a RingtonePreference item in it which will let the user decide the ringtone. More on Preferences [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html), also for [RingtonePreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/RingtonePreference.html)

You can later Retrieve this ringtone using sharedPreferences and even set a default value for it. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313542/ringtonepreference-default-value) too