# RingtonePreference defaultValue InflateException

Tags: android, default-value, ringtone

I use RingtonePreference and would like to use default notification sound as the default preference value. To achieve this I have followed advice in: [RingtonePreference Default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313542/ringtonepreference-default-value)

Sadly, in effect I got an `InflateException` that I cannot get rid of in any way. Is it a bug in android, my phone or am I doing something wrong?

My `OnCreate` method in `MyPreferenceActivity` class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

Relevant fragment of my `preferences.xml`:

```
<RingtonePreference
      android:key="ringtone_preference"
      android:ringtoneType="notification"
      android:showDefault="true"
      android:showSilent="true"
      android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
      android:title="Notification sound"
      android:summary=""
      />
```

LogCat of the exception:

```
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031): Failed to inflate
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1457)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at com.stanwise.timespacereminder.TSRPreferenceActivity.onCreate(TSRPreferenceActivity.java:44)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4586)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    ... 23 more
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.MultiSelectListPreference.onGetDefaultValue(MultiSelectListPreference.java:211)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.Preference.<init>(Preference.java:260)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.DialogPreference.<init>(DialogPreference.java:69)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.DialogPreference.<init>(DialogPreference.java:90)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    at android.preference.MultiSelectListPreference.<init>(MultiSelectListPreference.java:49)
06-06 22:44:07.697: E/ActivityThread(21031):    ... 26 more
```

I also tried inserting a string `DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI` instead of `content://settings/system/notification_sound`, but without any success. After removing the `android:defaultValue` field completely, everything works fine apart from the fact, that default value of my preference is Silent ringtone instaed of the default notification sound, which is unacceptable for me.

I have searched everywhere and cannot find a solution to this problem. If nothing else works, I will use a hack posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298638/1265432, but I would like to solve this properly.

**EDIT:** Problem exists on both my CM9 Motorola Defy and in Emulators of 4.0.4 (API 15) and 2.1 (API 7), so I think the phone is not a problem. Bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you log the value of `Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI` constant, then is it the same as you expect? If it is then it looks like the an Android bug. If it is not, then it just changes its value from device/API to device/API and then the only way is to set it programmatically.

Comment: Yes, `Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI == "content://settings/system/notification_sound"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug report for Android here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33220

In the meantime, I use the following workaround, which I found cleaner than the one linked in the question. I modified `OnCreate` method of `MyPreferenceActivity` to this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     Uri notificationSound = Uri.parse(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .getString("ringtone_preference", System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI.toString()));
    if (notificationSound.equals(System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
            .putString("ringtone_preference", System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI.toString())
            .commit();
    }

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented on your bug report with some insight on what the issue really is.

Anyway here's a simpler workaround that works for me:

Add a defaultValue for MultiSelectListPreference that comes after RingtonePreference in your preferences XML:

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
        ...
        android:defaultValue="@array/empty"
        ...
        />
```

And in your strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="empty"/>
```